# Creating an .ics calendar invitation with LotusScript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Use case: Send an invitation to an event using a .ics file and using preferably LotusScript.

Code is in a classic Domino Web application (you know, $$WebObscureHiddenField), business logic in in LotusScript, and I'm not too keen on writing anything else.

I've found the RFC which defines the format https://icalendar.org/RFC-Specifications/iCalendar-RFC-5545/ it seems straightforward to just write a text file following those conventions and then just attach it.

I've seen a similar question on SO, and Thorsten Link suggested to fill-in an 'Appointment' form with the relevant fields, but that seems sort of 'dirty' to me.

What's the best practice here?

Comment: its "Torsten" without an "h"... ;-) still haven't found another way to do this than "trial and error": Had to do a lot with ICS- Troubleshooting (mostly incoming from ticket - systems or other external tools) and can tell you: Every ICS file looks different... within the boundaries of the RFC... Which "features" you implement depends on how much effort you want to make...

Comment: Sorry for misspelling your name Torsten!

Comment: Doesn't the creation of a Notes document with the special fields used in a Calendar entry, when sent to an external email address, send the calendar entry as an ICS file automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to have a java servlet implement something like ical4j or other ics libraries which would then dynamically generate the ics.

Other approach I used for sending ics files was to write the necessary fields into a n ics file and attach it to the mail.

Comment: Hi Ueli, I was thinking of both solutions too. I think I’ll go with the second solution, I want it to be readable for the customer who is not familiar with Java.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building the ics file by myself; it was pretty straightforwards once I had understood the RFC and I just don't trust anything automagic.

Ueli, I gave you the correct answer 'tickmark'

```
'/*************************************************************************************
' * CalendarEntry Class
' * @author Andrew Magerman/Magerman/NotesNet
' * @version Sep 21, 2019
' *************************************************************************************/

Class CalendarEntry
    Public startdatetime As String
    Public enddatetime As String 
    Public summary As String
    Public location As String
    Public url As String
    Public description As String

' validator: https://icalendar.org/
' spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545

'/*************************************************************************************
' * Function as_NotesStream
' * @return: A NotesStream of the whole file, can be inputted directly into a NotesMimeEntity
' * @author Andrew Magerman/Magerman/NotesNet
' * @version Sep 22, 2019
' *************************************************************************************/
Function as_NotesStream As NotesStream
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim stream As NotesStream

    Set stream = session.Createstream() ' charset Unicode as default

    Call stream.WriteText("BEGIN:VCALENDAR", EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("PRODID:" & me.prodid(), EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("VERSION:2.0", EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("METHOD:REQUEST", EOL_CRLF)

    ' TIMEZONE Section - describes the timezone, the TZID is an internal reference
    Call stream.WriteText("BEGIN:VTIMEZONE" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("TZID:Europe/Berlin" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Berlin" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("BEGIN:DAYLIGHT" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("TZOFFSETFROM:+0100" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("TZOFFSETTO:+0200" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("TZNAME:CEST" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("DTSTART:19700329T020000" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("END:DAYLIGHT" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("BEGIN:STANDARD" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("TZOFFSETFROM:+0200" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("TZOFFSETTO:+0100" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("TZNAME:CET" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("DTSTART:19701025T030000" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("END:STANDARD" , EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("END:VTIMEZONE" , EOL_CRLF)

    Call stream.WriteText("BEGIN:VEVENT", EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("SUMMARY:" & me.summary, EOL_CRLF)
    '   Call stream.WriteText("PRIORITY:0", EOL_CRLF)
    '   Call stream.WriteText("CATEGORIES:GIG", EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("CLASS:PUBLIC", EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("UID:" & me.uid(), EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("DTSTAMP:" & me.dtstamp(), EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:" & me.startdatetime, EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:" & me.enddatetime, EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("URL:" & me.url, EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("DESCRIPTION:" & prepareTextCorrectly(me.description), EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("LOCATION:" & prepareTextCorrectly(me.location), EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("END:VEVENT", EOL_CRLF)
    Call stream.WriteText("END:VCALENDAR", EOL_CRLF)

    Set as_NotesStream = stream

    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
        Call logError
        Exit Function
    End Function

'/*************************************************************************************
' * Function domain: the customer-specific domain
' * @author Andrew Magerman/Magerman/NotesNet
' * @version Sep 22, 2019
' *************************************************************************************/
Function domain As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    domain = "example.com"

    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
        Call logError
        Exit Function
    End Function

'/*************************************************************************************
' * Function prodid:an id of the producer
' * @author Andrew Magerman/Magerman/NotesNet
' * @version Sep 22, 2019
' *************************************************************************************/
Function prodid As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    prodid = "-//YOUR MEGA PROD_ID//DE"

    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
        Call logError
        Exit Function
    End Function


'/*************************************************************************************
' * Function uid:An unique id for the calendar event
' * @author Andrew Magerman/Magerman/NotesNet
' * @version Sep 22, 2019
' *************************************************************************************/
Function uid As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim uuid As Variant
    uuid = Evaluate("@Unique")
    uid = startdatetime & "-" & CStr(uuid(0)) & "@" & domain

    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
        Call logError
        Exit Function
    End Function



'/*************************************************************************************
' * @author Andrew Magerman/Magerman/NotesNet
' * @version Sep 21, 2019
' *************************************************************************************/
Function dtstamp As String

    Dim dtTmp As NotesDateTime  
    Set dtTmp = New NotesDateTime(Now())    
    Const RFC554FORMATFORUTC = "yyyymmddThhmmssZ"       
    dtstamp = Format$(dtTmp.lsgmttime, RFC554FORMATFORUTC) 

End Function

'/*************************************************************************************
' * @author Andrew Magerman/Magerman/NotesNet
' * @version Sep 21, 2019
' *************************************************************************************/
Function ReplaceCRLFWithSlashN (value As String) As String

    Dim CRLF As String
    CRLF = Chr$(13) + Chr$(10)

    ReplaceCRLFWithSlashN = Replace(value, CRLF, "\n") 

End Function


'/*************************************************************************************
' * Function prepareTextCorrectly
' * @author Andrew Magerman/Magerman/NotesNet
' * @version Sep 21, 2019
' *************************************************************************************/
Function prepareTextCorrectly(value As string) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    prepareTextCorrectly = ReplaceCRLFWithSlashN(value)

    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
        Call logError
        Exit Function
    End Function



End Class
```

Comment: there's no resume :-)

Answer (score 0):

Replying to Andrew Magerman own solution:

I think there is a minor but substantial error in the "dtstamp" function, as the correct pattern for the format operation should be "yyyymmddThh**nn**ssZ".
The "nn" portion of the pattern stands for "minutes" while "mm" always stands for "months".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29773547)